# Как настроить совместный доступ к папке в локальной сети между Windows и Ubuntu с возможностью редактировать файлы

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, samba

Попробовал создать общую папку из под Windows и подключиться к ней из Ubuntu.
Подключился без проблем, но вот файлы в эту папку не могу добавлять из Ubuntu, хотя в настройках общего доступа в Windows выставлены все галочки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пошел от обратного: создал папку на Ubuntu, к которой открыл общий доступ и подключил ее в Windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь уже лучше, могу создавать файлы из обеих ОС, но вот редактировать не могу, только переименовывать и удалять. А вот отредактированный сохранить не дает. Как в Windows (если файл создан из Ubuntu) так и наоборот.

Права на папку сейчас такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда я добавляю файл из Windows, то не могу редактировать его из Ubuntu пока не выполню команду `sudo chmod -R a+rwx 1`, но это команду мне приходится выполнять каждый раз, когда я добавляю новый файл, это неудобно. Не пойму как сделать чтобы сразу была возможность редактировать.

Comment: а права на каталог/файлы какие? `ls -al /path/to/dir/1`

Comment: @Fat-Zer дополнил вопрос

Comment: на будущее: текст из консоли можно копировать...

Comment: https://smb-conf.ru/absolyutnaya-fajlopomojka.html пробовал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации того, что в win-мире называется «общими папками» применяется протокол [SMB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block). В nix-мире основной его реализацией является samba.

На сколько я вижу, возможности по конфигурации пользовательских шар (*usershare*, те что создаются непривилегированными пользователями в том числе через гуйню) в samba до сих пор довольно убогие. У меня так и не получилось придумать, как в сносном виде настроить её в режиме «общей файлопомойки». Так что предлагаю вариант, как это сделать по-нормальному:

---

- Создать специального пользователя для доступа по `smb`:

  ```
  useradd -r sambaguest -d /var/lib/samba/ -s /bin/false
  ```

  где:

  - `-r` — создать системного пользователя
  - `-d /var/lib/samba/` — просто произвольный условно-подходящий по смыслу домашний каталог.
  - -s `/bin/false` — логин-оболочка, которая запрещает пользователю вход

  см. подробности в [`man useradd`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=useradd&category=8&russian=0)
- Создать специальный каталог для шары и дать права

  ```
  mkdir -p /mnt/my_share
  ```

  И задать его владельца и права:

  ```
  chown root:sambaguest /mnt/my_share
  chmod 2775 /mnt/my_share
  ```

  Здесь важно, что устанавливается группа `sambaguest` и [setgid-бит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suid), который делает так, что вновь созданные файлы и каталоги будут наследовать группу и права родительского каталога.
- В `/etc/samba/smb.conf` задать в секции `global`, собственно этого пользователя как гостевого:

  ```
  [global]
    ; ...
    guest account = sambaguest ; пользователь от имени которого будут работать гости
  ```

  И в том же `/etc/samba/smb.conf` добавить описание новой шары:

  ```
  [my]                    ; Видимое название шары
    comment = Любимая файлопомойка ; произвольный комментарий
    path = /mnt/my_share
    browseable = yes      ; разрешить получение её в общем списке
    writeable = yes       ; разрешить запись 
    guest ok = yes        ; разрешить доступ гостям
    create mask = 0664    ; маска прав на создаваемые файлы
    directory mask = 0775 ; маска прав на создаваемые каталоги
  ```

  см. подробности в [`man smb.conf`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=smb.conf&category=5&russian=2)
- Перезапустить samba-демона:

  ```
  systemctl restart smbd
  ```
- Добавить своего пользователя в группу `sambaguest`:

  ```
  gpasswd sambaguest -a engene
  ```

  После этого перелогиниться. (Хотя в свежей бубунте со свежим logind опять всё поломали и окромя релогина придётся явно убить сессию пользователя: `loginctl terminate-user engene`.)
- По желанию, можно симлинкнуть этот каталог в свой домашний:

  ```
  ln -s /mnt/my_share ~/share
  ```

Всё это создаст полноценную совместную файлопомойку: у любого клиента в локальной сити, как и у локальных пользователей в группе `sambaguest` будет возможность создавать, изменять и удалять все файлы в указанном каталоге.